# Webservices with dynamic urls

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have a project with several references to webservices and have made two different config files (one for dev/stage and one for production) with different URLs to the services.  Whichever URL the webservices were originally added using works fine, but the other one fails.

For example, if I use the "add web reference" button to add a service at server1 everything works fine when I run my application.  If I then switch out the config file so it's trying to use an identical service on server2 my application no longer works.  Every call .net makes to the webservice returns null.  If I use fiddler to see the XML the servers return they look identical.

Also, anytime the web services get rebuilt (even if nothing changes) I have to refresh all the references in my application.  Don't know if that's related.

What would cause this and is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a big project that has this.

A user creates an account with it's own web service endpoint, so I need them to be dynamic.

The trick is to always change the Endpoint address before each call to the service.

example of a `Find` service

```
FindClient wsFin = new FindClient();
wsFin.Endpoint.Address =
    new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(clientUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/Find.svc");
```

just as a note: for WCF Services I have preferred to create a proxy using the `svcutil` instead of adding the reference, but for `asmx` web services, I did add reference :)

Comment: I guess I should clarify that this isn't a WCF or asmx webservice, but a plain old SOAP service generated by Peoplesoft.

Comment: as long as you have the `wsdl` you can generate the proxy using `svcutil`, no matter what it is and in what language was created!